# Connect to a Server Computer over the Internet (Cloud) from Android device and DDNS, is it possible?

Tags: android, sockets, cloud, port-number, noip

I am working on a Android project, I want to connect my App on an android device to a (Server Computer) over the Internet (Cloud) using sockets. And  I don't want to use Web services for that connection ((I already used this technique , but it is not working in my case as it is more complicated and have too much delay)) .

-Android will work as a Client
-Server Computer will work as a Server

Is it possible to have a DDNS (like NO-IP) on the Server with a specific port number (like 77444) to listen to the Client (Android App) and establish connection and data transferring between them??

[image: <b>Click here to see Architectural Design of the project</b></br>]

Any support is appreciated

Comment: You cannot use your Android device as a server using a mobile connection. The mobile provider does not allow it.

Comment: `Connect to server over internet from Android device`. In that case your Android device runs the client. Pretty unclear what you really have ant want.

Comment: Yes @greenapps you are right, I just changed the title of the question.. by making the android works like a sever, I am saying that from the client and server in socket prospective.. at that time the client is listening to any connection request from the server (Android)

Comment: By the way, I have done this project in a local network, and I want to know your suggestions and ideas about cloud. 
Thank you so much @greenapps

Comment: `at that time the client is listening to any connection request from the server`. No. It is not like that. Servers listen for connection requests from clients.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps, I was misunderstand the situation.. I am re-correcting the question..

Comment: In my case, I have several mobile devices that are connected to this PC,, The PC have a big task and distribute this task among the mobile devices, then the mobiles execute the tasks then return the result to the client..

-From the Client/Server prospective: As you said, The PC is Server.
-But from the distributed computing systems, the Androids are Servers, as they get tasks from clients and execute it for the client and return it to the PC (Client)

Comment: `over the internet. (Cloud)`. Sorry but what has a connection over the internet between an Android device and your pc to do with cloud?

Comment: `several mobile devices that are connected to this PC,`. Now what do you mean exactly with that? How are they connected?

Comment: Please do not use the meaning of server/client in two ways. Keep with the meaning with sockets only.

Comment: `using sockets. And I don't want to use Web services for that `.  What are you comparing here? To connect devices/applications you can use sockets.  But not webservices. Again a misconception.